# How to add : to one line in a file

Tags: bash

I have a file with multiple lines but I want to add : to space out the sections. So for example I have...

```
Last Name First Name User ID email
Smith John 123456789 johnsmith@gmail.com
```

And I am trying to only add : to the first line spacing out the four categories of information like

```
Last Name : First Name : User ID : email
Smith John 123456789 johnsmith@gmail.com
```

I know you can just vi and edit the file but that is way too easy. Is there a more efficient way to do this with one line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add colons to the first line and only the first line:

```
$ sed -r '1 s/([^ ]+ ){2}/&: /g' file
Last Name : First Name : User ID : email
Smith John 123456789 johnsmith@gmail.com
```

To make those changes and save the file in place, use the sed's `-i` option

```
sed -ir '1 s/([^ ]+ ){2}/&: /g' file
```

#### How it works

- `-r`

  This selects extended regular expression syntax
- `1 s/([^ ]+ ){2}/&: /g`

  The `1` at the beginning selects line 1.  Substitution commands have the form `s/old/new/` where `old` here is two words and the space which follows:  `([^ ]+ ){2}`.  The `new` here is what was matched, `&`, followed by a colon and a space.  The final `g` tells sed to do this repeatedly on the line.

#### Mac OSX or Other BSD System

With a BSD sed, try:

```
sed -i '' -E '1 s/([^ ][^ ]* ){2}/&: /g' file
```

Comment: Thanks John. I will accept answer in 5 minutes, this is what I was trying to do efficiently.

Comment: What if I want to add them to the entire file by chance ?

Comment: @MarcusBurkhart Remove the `1` and the substitution will apply to all lines: